# Algorithm to calculate N paths from K set

Tags: algorithm, combinations, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm looking for an algorithm that can calculate N paths from K set where N=10 and K=32. This is not a combinatory algo, I don't need every number in every position.

So basically I need to be able to find the distinct paths of up to 10 elements in a collection of 32.

Edit: 
If I have a set of numbers

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
```

I would like to get every unique path of 10. So an example would be

```
Path 1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
Path 2 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11}
Path 3 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12}
```

Down the line I would like something like this:

```
Path N { 3,5,6,8,9,12,14,17,18,19 }
```

Since I need every possible path consisting of 10 elements from the larger set.

Comment: I don't understand the question; could you provide an example for the problem?

Comment: @Codor I just updated this question for you.

Comment: Isn't it just all unique permutations of length 10? Something like this: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/ but only increasing numbers

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here :

[Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n?lq=1)

Note that you will get 64512240 paths. You may want to think a bit about it before filling your RAM with them.